# What is the most efficient way to sort hashes in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, hash

I am trying to sort about 20 hashes in ruby based on one of the attributes of the array.  I want to only return the top 3 **hash keys**, but I don't want to have to compare each one.

Here is an example below of something similar to what I am trying to sort.  I want to sort based on powerrank.

```
["green", {:price=>24.88, :numreviews=>822, :avgStarsRank=>41.0, :reviewsrank=>28, :powerrank=>73.976}]

["steve", {:price=>14.96, :numreviews=>3, :avgStarsRank=>40.0, :reviewsrank=>0, :powerrank=>42.992000000000004}]

["joey", {:price=>40.27, :numreviews=>814, :avgStarsRank=>44.0, :reviewsrank=>28, :powerrank=>80.054}]

["board", {:price=>14.96, :numreviews=>3, :avgStarsRank=>40.0, :reviewsrank=>0, :powerrank=>47}]

["john", {:price=>40.27, :numreviews=>814, :avgStarsRank=>44.0, :reviewsrank=>28, :powerrank=>16}]
```

For this, all  I would want back would an array with ["joey", "green", "board"].  Any suggestions on how to tackle this issue?

**Edit:** Here is the example in the original hash form:

```
powerrankings =
    {
        "green"=>{:price=>24.88, :numreviews=>822, :avgStarsRank=>41.0, :reviewsrank=>28, :powerrank=>73.976}, 
        "steve"=>{:price=>14.96, :numreviews=>3, :avgStarsRank=>40.0, :reviewsrank=>0, :powerrank=>42.992000000000004}, 
        "joey"=>{:price=>40.27, :numreviews=>814, :avgStarsRank=>44.0, :reviewsrank=>28, :powerrank=>80.054}}
        "board"=>{:price=>14.96, :numreviews=>3, :avgStarsRank=>40.0, :reviewsrank=>0, :powerrank=>47}, 
        "john"=>{:price=>40.27, :numreviews=>814, :avgStarsRank=>44.0, :reviewsrank=>28, :powerrank=>16}
    }
```

Comment: You have some objects. Are they supposed to be included in one object? It is not clear whether you want to sort arrays or hashes.

Comment: @sawa I am trying to sort hashes.  The example above is as a result of a .each through an object

Comment: @sawa Just edited the question with a better example of what i am originally dealing with.  Does what I am asking make more sense?

Comment: The wording is still tricky, but is better than before. But that code that you added is invalid. Also, it is now not clear what that original example that you had is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `powerrankings` is not as you showed but is rather,

```
powerrankings = {
  "green" => {:price=>24.88, :numreviews=>822, :avgStarsRank=>41.0, :reviewsrank=>28, :powerrank=>73.976}, 
  "steve" => {:price=>14.96, :numreviews=>3, :avgStarsRank=>40.0, :reviewsrank=>0, :powerrank=>42.992000000000004}, 
  "joey" => {:price=>40.27, :numreviews=>814, :avgStarsRank=>44.0, :reviewsrank=>28, :powerrank=>80.054},
  "board" => {:price=>14.96, :numreviews=>3, :avgStarsRank=>40.0, :reviewsrank=>0, :powerrank=>47}, 
  "john" => {:price=>40.27, :numreviews=>814, :avgStarsRank=>44.0, :reviewsrank=>28, :powerrank=>16}
}
```

then,

```
powerrankings.sort_by{|_, h| h[:powerrank]}.reverse.first(3).map(&:first)
# => ["joey", "green", "board"]
```

Comment: As an alternative to `.sort_by{|_, h| h[:powerrank]}.reverse`, consider `.sort_by{|_, h| -h[:powerrank]}` (sort on negative powerrank) which does not need to reverse the entire array but yields the correct order right away.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers No I will not. What is the point of doing so? Downsides of what you suggest are that (i) it is slower, and (ii) it cannot be generalized to other comparable items on which `-` is not defined.

Comment: I was under the impression it should be faster since it omits reversing the Array while not measurably increasing runtime by adding the negation operation. Do you really think it would be slower? Why? (ps. obviously I was aware it only works on classes which respond to `-` but that's obvious, and not a real downside in this specific case.)

Comment: For what it's worth; I did some quick and simple benchmark where there is hardly a difference between both cases (on a Hash with 10M elements) both seem roughly the same. Slightly faster still seems `[-3..-1].reverse` instead of `reverse.first(3)`, which reverses only the last 3 elements and sorts without the `-` operation. Code [here](http://pastebin.com/wx8sY43x) for transparency. No big differences for smaller samples so it does not really matter in the end.